# How can I automate a GUI App?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, automation, testing, application

I need to automate a small GUI Windows app. It needs to be run twice a week to synchronise two databases, but with no operator intelligence behind it.

Literally, it's launch the app, and perform two button clicks, and forget.

I've seen ClickOK, but the single review of it I've found isn't very favourable. Is there anything better out there?

Answer (score 7):

It's been a few years since I've used it, but [Auto-It](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) has worked a treat for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is popular among the folks over on Super User.